# Minimum RAM that Weblogic Admin Console can run under

Tags: weblogic

What is the minimum amount of RAM that the Weblogic Admin Consoel (version 10.3.2) will run under?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

256MB is usually a safe bet but for our larger production domains, we use as much as 512mb. In addition to the domain size, your WLDF settings can affect the required heap size.

On a test system, you can probably get away with 128mb.

Answer (score -1):

4 GB

[Setting the memory arguments for the WebLogic application servers for SAS® Financial Management](http://support.sas.com/kb/32/451.html)